# radioboxes only adds values on change, but doesn't subtract

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions. One adds value from `checkboxes` and the other adds values from `radioboxes` to `var tot`.

The problem is that `radiobox` only adds value to `var tot`, but doesn't subtracts when unchecked.
I didn't have this problem until I scoped out the `var tot`, but it had to be done so that both functions could access it. Here is a code sample with the problem in action:

```js
$(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false);
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').prop('checked', false);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tot = 0;
  $('#usertotal').text('0 SEK')

  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      tot -= parseInt($(this).val());
    } else {
      tot += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
    $('#usertotal').text(tot + ' SEK')
  });

  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      tot += parseInt($(this).val());
    } else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      tot -= parseInt($(this).val());
    }
    $('#usertotal').text(tot + ' SEK')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="160 Yes">till 20
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="someclass" value="5 Yes"> 20
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="29 Yes">BV

<div class="col-lg-4 col-mg-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 calculation-window">
  Totalt: <span id="usertotal"></span>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ys1b9Lwv/12/**

Comment: This has been discussed in another question. [The radio button "change" event only fires when activated, not when deactivated.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18034498/1679849) You might find it easier to just repeat the calculations from scratch at every onchange event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't get de-select in radio box. so my solution is to fire deselect by ourself and identify already selected radio box. I am using class to achieve it.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {

        tot += parseInt($(this).val());
   $(this).addClass("sel");
  $('input[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').not($(this)).trigger('deselect'); 
    $('#usertotal').text(tot + ' SEK')
  });
   $('input[type="radio"]').bind('deselect', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("sel"))
    {
    $(this).removeClass("sel");
      tot -= parseInt($(this).val());
       $('#usertotal').text(tot + ' SEK')
    }});
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be that radio buttons don't fire the change event when they're unselected. Adding logging into the radio change event confirms this.

There are a few ways to solve this but I think the most elegant is to refactor the calculation of the total into a separate function, that checks the values of all the components involved in the sum / total.

I've come up with [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld051pne/3/):

```
var tot = 0;
$('#usertotal').text('0 SEK');

var update_tot = function () {
  tot = 0; // reset

  // sum of inputs that are checked
  $('input:checkbox,input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      tot += parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  $('#usertotal').text(tot + ' SEK');
};

$('input:checkbox,input[type="radio"]').change(update_tot);
```

---

A cleaner rewrite of this could be:

```
var tot = 0;
$('#usertotal').text('0 SEK');

$('input:checkbox,input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
  tot = 0; // reset

  // sum of inputs that are checked
  $('input:checkbox,input[type="radio"]')
    .filter(':checked')
    .each(function(){
      tot += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

  $('#usertotal').text(tot + ' SEK');
});
```