# how to make action after clicking a radio button on a site made by html, css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have made a a site using html and css where users use radio buttons to make choice now I am looking forward to putting action to the choices made. If a user chooses an option and action should be made, however I do not know how to put action to a radio button action. I require help please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Take some time to look over [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include some code that you've been using, as well as what actions you would like to perform when the user presses a radio button.

Comment: Have a look at addEventListener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener with 'change' type

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `addEventListener` method. So, say you have a the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1">
```

Then you can use this code:

```
var radio = document.getElementsByName("myRadio")
radio.forEach(r => r.addEventListener('change', myFunc))
```

You can also bind the function in your HTML, using the `onchange` attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" onchange="myFunc()">
```

You can see more details in previous questions that seem very similar to yours:

- [onchange not working with radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795392/onchange-not-working-with-radio-button)
- [OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)
- [Radio Input onChange only fires once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450285/radio-input-onchange-only-fires-once)

Also, as suggested by @devdgehog, you could give a look at the documentation on:

- addEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- inputs's onchange: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event